# Getting _jsonparsefailure with valid json in logstash

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack

I currently and attempting to send a json through logstash to elasticsearch. However, I am getting an error that there is a jsonparsefailure even though I have validated my json as being in the proper format. What could be my issue? Below is my config file and my json

```
input{
 file{
        path => "/Users/CFP668/Downloads/gs-accessing-data-mysql-master/complete/example.json"
        codec => json
        start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "test123" 
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

```
"{\"request_id\":1,\"requestDetail_id\":0,\"enrichedContent\":\"enrich cont example\",\"statusCode\":\"P\",\"reasonDesc\":\"This is a test\",\"createdBy\":\"Sarah\",\"createdDate\":\"Sep 24, 2010\"}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your json isn't really valid for Logstash, you have a backslash before the double quotes on your keys and your json object is also between double quotes.

Your json lines on the source file should be something like this:

```
{"request_id":1,"requestDetail_id":0,"enrichedContent":"enrich cont example","statusCode":"P","reasonDesc":"This is a test","createdBy":"Sarah","createdDate":"Sep 24, 2010"}
```

The way to work with your current json line, without changing how it is generated, is to use a gsub on you message to change `"{` to `{`, `}"` to `}` and to remove the backslashes `\`

The following filter pipeline does that:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message","^\"{","{"]
        gsub => ["message","}\"$","}"]
        gsub => ["message","[\\]",""]
    }
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

And you can remove the `codec => "json"` from your input block.